# Python DataFrames putting multipule dataframes into a single Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

## Import the required modules

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Enable inline plotting
%matplotlib inline
```

## Set the date range and the stock code of the stock

```
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
Stock_List = ('BHP.Ax','AMP.AX','PRR.AX')
Stock_Code = "BHP.AX"
df_Stock_Code = pd.DataFrame()
Results = pd.DataFrame()
```

## Loops though codes and gets data

```
for Stock_Code in Stock_List:
     #Queries yahoo website for asx code froma start and end date
     f = web.DataReader(Stock_Code, 'yahoo', start, end)
     f['Stock_Code'] = Stock_Code 
     df_Stock_Code = f
```

## Concatenates all of the data frames into on but it fails for some reason

```
Results = [Results,df_Stock_Code] 
    
df_Results = pd.Concat(Results)
```

Comment: ok.. do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry long time since I have used stackover flow.  The above code works until I try and combine all of the dataframes into a single dataframe using the "Concat".  I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the original code, `df_Stock_Code` is treated as a list of dataframes. However, in the `for loop`, the current dataframe is being assigned to it rather than appending the latest dataframe to it.

The result is that in the concatenation step, `df_Stock_Code` is just a single dataframe referring to the last stock in your `Stock_List`. `Results` is also never used in the loop and is just an empty dataframe from when it was initialized at the start.

Try this instead:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
Stock_List = ('BHP.Ax','AMP.AX','PRR.AX')
Stock_Code = "BHP.AX"
df_Stock_Code = pd.DataFrame()
Results = []

for Stock_Code in Stock_List:
    #Queries yahoo website for asx code froma start and end date
    f = web.DataReader(Stock_Code, 'yahoo', start, end)
    f['Stock_Code'] = Stock_Code 
    df_Stock_Code = Results.append(f)

df_Results = pd.concat(Results)
print df_Results
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues and showing me how it is done. Much appriciated

Comment: No problem, glad i could help!